# webpack 4 requirejs 2 module parse failed: unexpected character '#'

Tags: webpack, requirejs

I rpm-installed requirejs then webpack reported a module parse failure, specifically with requirejs's included r.js code with an octothorp character. I've seen several online reports about webpack and requirejs not playing nice, with some people recommending to use webpack's raw loader when webpacking requirejs. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I separated out the require.js from r.js (looks like r.js is for server-side node). Not wanting to spend too much time trying to webpack-ize require.js, I'm gonna punt and just load require.js in the webpage before loading the webpack bundles. Unless someone offers some tips ...

Comment: I did try the raw-loader but it output require.js as a string in the bundle code. Just for fun I eval'd the string but that blew up :-)